# Seeking to understand this syntax in C# [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="AdventureWorks2008R2")]

Tags: c#, syntax, custom-attributes

I added a Linq to SQL data access class to my project and dragged a table to the design surface and I looked at the code generated in the .cs file. I am trying to understand this snippet:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.DatabaseAttribute(Name="AdventureWorks2008R2")]
public partial class AdventureWorksDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    private static System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MappingSource mappingSource = new AttributeMappingSource();
```

I think I understand attributes in a general way and even in this specific case but my real question is "What is meant by the double colon syntax?" Is the above attribute a "global attribute" as discussed elsewhere (for example, here at  http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-and-reading-global-attributes-in-csharp[1](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/creating-and-reading-global-attributes-in-csharp) )

A corollary question would be how to search for the meaning of the :: syntax in Google and/or within StackOverflow? I've tried placing it within quotes and ended up posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace alias qualifier (::) is used to look up identifiers. It is always positioned between two identifiers, as in this example:

```
global::System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

The namespace alias qualifier can be `global`. This invokes a lookup in the global namespace, rather than an aliased namespace.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d.aspx

Comment: Just-a-link answers are discouraged on SO. Much better to provide a small abstract or quote the most relevant part here (in addition to the link). Assume the link goes dead after some time.

Comment: Good point. Also, what about this related item (quoted from above)? "how to search for the meaning of the :: syntax in Google and/or within StackOverflow?"